# ionic angularjs give variable trough tabcontroller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am totally new with angularjs and the ionic framework, but for a school project I need to make a app so I thought this was the best was.

But right now I face a problem, I am using the ionic tabcontroller and I want to give a variable with the tabs.

Here is a screenshot to explain how it need to works.

[image]

I hope someone can help me.

**Edit:**

routes.js:

```
.state('tabsController.dos', {
url: '/dos/:itemid',
views: {
  'tab1': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/dos.html',
    controller: 'dosCtrl',
    controller: function ($stateParams, $location, $http, $scope, $sce) {
      $scope.reload = function() {
        $state.reload();
      };
      console.log($stateParams.itemid);
      $http.get('https://host/app/php/info.php?landid='+$stateParams.itemid+'&actie=dos')
      .success(function(response){
        $scope.dynamicHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(response);
      });
    }
  }
}
})
.state('tabsController.dont', {
url: '/donts/:itemid',
views: {
  'tab2': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/dont.html',
    controller: 'dontCtrl'
  }
}
})
```

Comment: is this ionic 1 or ionic 2? and can you add the relevant code?

Comment: @suraj Thanks for your quick responds the version of ionic is:  * Ionic, v1.3.2